# Recuperar un repositorio git?

Tags: php, linux, git, git-push

una persona hecho rm en el directorio principal de mi dominio, ha eliminado absolutamente todo. He recuperado los subdominios ya que únicamente tenían algunos scripts, el problema es el dominio principal.

Yo tengo un proyecto en httpdocs/ y un repositorio git creado con plesk. Mi servidor hacia de repositorio remoto. En local tengo todos los ficheros ¿cómo hago para que el repo remoto se actualice según mi local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes forzar el push con la bandera `f`.

```
git push -f <RepositorioRemoto> <branch>
```

Pero también puedes hacer un push normal si haces un commit más nuevo en tu repositorio local y posteriormente haces un push hacia tu servidor.

Comment: Gracias!! casi muero de los nervios. He aprendido algo, no darle acceso a cualquier gili*****

Comment: En general la regla es nunca confiar en tus usuarios. No se sabe cuando va a salir un listillo

Answer (score 1):

La solución ha sido:

1- Crear un nuevo repositorio en Plesk (que será el nuevo remoto).

2- Añadir el nuevo repositorio remoto en local.

3- Hacer un push de todo.